# UITableview cell label font size not set first time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uifont

I have a `UITableview` in a cell are many labels. I want to set font size according to the device in `cellForRowAt` method but the font size is not set the first time. when I scroll tableview then will back to screen then font size are set. How to resolve this issue. Below code is using in `cellForRowAt`

```
           cell.lbl_desc.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true
            cell.lbl_price.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true
            cell.lbl_qty.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=true

        let bounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let height = bounds.size.height
        switch height
        {
        case 568.0:
            print("iPhone 5")

            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(13)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(13)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(13)
        case 667.0:
            print("iPhone 6")

            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(15)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(15)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(15)
        case 736.0:
            print("iPhone 6+")

            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(16)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(16)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(16)
        default:
            print("iPad")

            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(18)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(18)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(18)
        }
```

Comment: maybe you can show some of your codes?

Comment: I added the code.

Comment: is this exact code what are you using in your codebase ??     You do not use  **break;** after each case statement ... it may be a reason you can recheck

Comment: yes is this exact code.

Comment: `switch ([error code]) {
    case kPFErrorObjectNotFound:
        // Handle error.
        break;
    case kPFErrorConnectionFailed:
        // Handle error.
        break;
    default:
        // Handle error.
}`

Comment: Try like this ... Put the font code in cell class awakeFromNib

Comment: I added break but don't work.

Comment: @Bala Karunakaran I also add in cell class awakeFromNib then app got the crash of fatal error found nil.

Comment: add whole code for cellForRowAtIndexPath in question.

Comment: I think the issue is your label is not initialised at first time... Because you set the same label font to that ... Check with exception break point where you got the nil value.

Comment: @BalaKarunakaran how to initialized label first time in cell class.

Comment: Add your cellForRowAtIndexPath full code in Question

Comment: It Resolves by added   table_view.setNeedsLayout(), table_view.layoutIfNeeded()  in viewdidload but some time scroll font size mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change font in willDisplay method .

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }
```

Comment: I am using it but not change

Comment: @GauravGupta Are you setting the font on the `cell` input parameter of this method? If you are getting the cell using the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...)` it will not work. Please see also my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040564/1245231

Answer (score 1):

After each case statement you should use a **break;** please try something like below

```
switch (mode) {
    case kEditGameModeEdit:
        // ...
        break;
    case kEditGameModeNewGame:
        // ...
        break;

    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try with this code:**

Put below lines in one Constant file,

```
let IS_IPHONE_5 = (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
let IS_IPHONE_6 = (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
let IS_IPHONE_6P = (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)
let IS_IPAD = (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad)
```

Now in your cellForRowAt write this code,

```
if IS_IPAD {
        cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(18)
        cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(18)
        cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(18)
    }
    else {
        if IS_IPHONE_5 {
            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(13)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(13)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(13)
        }
        else if IS_IPHONE_6 {
            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(15)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(15)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(15)
        }
        else if IS_IPHONE_6P {
            cell.lbl_desc.font =  cell.lbl_desc.font.withSize(16)
            cell.lbl_price.font =  cell.lbl_price.font.withSize(16)
            cell.lbl_qty.font =  cell.lbl_qty.font.withSize(16)
        }
    }
```

Wish this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#define SCREEN_WIDTH ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width)
#define SCREEN_HEIGHT ([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)
#define SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH (MAX(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))
#define SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH (MIN(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT))

#define IS_IPHONE_4_OR_LESS (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH < 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_5 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 568.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6 (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 667.0)
#define IS_IPHONE_6P (IS_IPHONE && SCREEN_MAX_LENGTH == 736.0)

if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
  [cell.lblProductName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:36]];
}
else if (IS_IPHONE_6){
  [cell.lblProductName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:37]];
}
else{
  [cell.lblProductName setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:38]];
}
```

I m using above code and it's working fine for me.