# UILabel's font not adjusting until view reappears

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uifont

Using the storyboard I created a tableview with cells that have labels.

I want to be able to easily assign the same font to all labels in my app so I created some fonts in a helper file (smallFont, mediumFont, and largeFont) and in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` I set each label to use the font I want (i.e. cell.label.font = Common.fonts.mediumFont).

The first time the tableview displays it is using the font defined in the storyboard and it doesn't use the font I programed in until you navigate away from the view and back.

I can eliminate the visual resizing by changing the storyboard to use the same font that I place programmatically but I want to be able to change the fonts across the entire app just by adjusting the font in the Common file.

How can I override the storyboard's font and force it to use the programmed in font when the view first appears?

Edit: To add some more information.

When I scroll the table the label fonts change from the storyboard size to the programmed fonts.

Comment: It sounds like you have your delegate/dataSource methods set correctly, and if you are changing the font inside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` already the only thing that I can think of would be to make a call to `tableView.reloadData()`.  I don't like that solution, so maybe someone else will know of a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I tried using tableView.reloadData() in "viewDidLoad" and put a breakpoint on it to verify that it gets called but it is still using the storyboard font until you navigate to another screen and back.

Comment: @AgRizzo The label font is set in `tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)` which is where the cells are created.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The font is set in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I've verified the font is set by adding a break point there. To be really sure the method gets called I've also changed the background color of the UILabel in the same method. But while the background color was changed, the font remains the same as it is set in the Storyboard. The proper font is used only when child ViewController is displayed and dismissed and all cells are refreshed again.

Comment: @CSjunkie Finally I was able to fix it. Here is how: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47040564/1245231

Answer (score 7):

I have fixed it by setting the font in both `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` methods.

The `willDisplayCell` is implemented this way:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, 
               forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    // e.g.
    let myCell = cell as! MyCustomCell
    myCell.label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 17.0)
}
```

**Note**: that the font is set on the `cell` input parameter in the `willDisplayCell` method, as shown in the code above. If the cell is taken from the `tableView` using the `tableView.dequeueReusableCell(...)` it will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try modifying the font from awakeFromNib from the cell class?

Here's a sample:

```
class CustomFontCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        titleLabel.font = Common().appleBerryFont(size: 28.0)
    }    
}

struct Common {

    func appleBerryFont(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
        return UIFont(name: "appleberry", size: size)!
    }

}
```

[image: Noteworth font in storyboard, Appleberry font applied at runtime]

Typically, awakeFromNib is used to perform additional initializations.

Comment: Thanks for the advice but I have attempted this already and it did not work :(

Comment: Having the same issue. Even though I change font to e.g. `UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)` in the `awakeFromNib()` and also in the `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)` the font is changed to what is set in the StoryBoard. The proper font is used only after child ViewController is displayed and dismissed or when table cells are scrolled outside of screen and get refreshed.

Comment: I can imagine that the appleberry Font is not included in your current project, did you check that?

Answer (score 0):

First, replace your common method by create a font. I cannot think of any cases that this won't work.

```
label.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(20)
```

Assuming this works, use a break point to debug your original code. You need to make sure that on the first time, your testFont line is executed and with a valid not-nil value.

```
let testFont = Common.fonts.mediumFont
label.font = testFont
```

Comment: Even using your suggested system font the font did not update until the second time the view was displayed

Comment: @CSjunkie What type of navigation are you making for this to work? Can you post your code please? Are you 100 percent sure that this set font line is executed on the first time?

Comment: I am using a tab bar navigator and switching between tabs causes this to work. The same chunk of code is also setting the label text and that is coming through fine so the code is definitely being executed. The code is very long, but I can even put the font change as the last line in the function before the return and still no change.

Comment: @CSjunkie You have to show us all your codes in this situation. For a tableview in a nav bar, `cellForRow` SHOULD NOT BE CALLED when you switch between tabs. So something must be trigger when you switch around and that updates the font. If your code is too long to be posted here, use this site https://paste.ofcode.org/

Comment: I used breakpoints and found that there is a call to `reloadData()` when it transitions from the tab bar which calls `cellForRow`. I hesitate to post the code because it is not mine and I do not have permission to do so.

Comment: @CSjunkie That's fine not showing the code but your situation doesn't make sense. When you first enter this view controller, you can take it as `reloadData()` is called. So why the second call to this method works but not the first time? I suggest you to put more breaks points or see what else happened before you call `reloadData()` for the second time

Comment: I agree that it does not make sense, what makes less sense is that this tab is not the "home" tab. In other words I can navigate from "home" to this tab, get the wrong font, navigate back to "home" and then back to this tab and get the correct font.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm you can try prepareForReuse() instead, this function is use to perform some final modifications or resetting:

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()
    titleLabel.font = Common().appleBerryFont(size: 28.0)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however this did not solve the issue. In addition, Apple's documentation states not to use this function for anything content related: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse

Comment: yeah this is last resort for debugging, if this also doesnt work, sure there is some parts of your code that is not properly implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Another technique - subclass UILabel and set the font there. Use that label in your storyboard where needed. For example:

```
import UIKit
class StandardLabel: UILabel {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit(){
        self.font = Common.fonts.mediumFont
    }
}
```

Then in your storyboards, change your label class to StandardLabel.

Comment: this would probably work but it would add more problems. I would need a different subclass for each font size I want to use (3 at the moment) and if I want to change the size of an individual label (if I want a medium one to be a large one now) I have to change its class and outlets to go along with that, creating more work than using the storyboard would.

Answer (score 0):

In your custom Label you should override

```
override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
}
```

and make Font changes there